# Xamarin.Forms and AppCenter: event not tracked in Release mode for Android devices

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, analytics, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-build

I've developed a small **Xamarin.Forms.Shell app**: this app contains **4 tabs**, where the default **HomePage** contains some basic informations.

I'm using **AppCenter** to track some **events**, like pages displays, users clicks, APIs calls,...

In the `App.xaml.cs` I've specified 2 cases (Debug/prod) to register **AppCenter**:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    // AppCenter
#if DEBUG
    AppCenter.Start("ios=xxx;" +
            "android=yyy;",
            typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
#else
    AppCenter.Start("ios=aaa;" +
            "android=bbb;",
            typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
#endif
}
```

Then, on the **HomePage's** `ViewModel`, I'm doing this:

```
public HomeViewModel()
{
    _eventTracker = new AppCenterEventTracker();
    //...
    _eventTracker.Display("HomePage");
}
```

Which refers to:

```
public virtual void Display(string page, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> optionalParams = null)
{
    var mainParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(EventProperty.Page, page),
    };
    Analytics.TrackEvent(EventType.Display, BuildParameters(mainParams, optionalParams));
}
```

On the **NewsPage** `ViewModel` that is displayed through another tab, the code is:

```
public NewsViewModel()
{
    _eventTracker = new AppCenterEventTracker();
    //...
    _eventTracker.Display("NewsPage");
}
```

This works well in **Debug** mode for **iOS** and **Android**: I can retrieve this event in **AppCenter** for all pages (the **HomePage** and other pages like **NewsPage**)

But when the app is built in **Release** mode, or through **AppCenter**, it's not the case for the **HomePage**: **I only retrieve this event for iOS, but not for Android**. For the other pages like **NewsPage**, I don't encounter any issue: the display is well taken into account...

So I think that the issue is related to the tab that is displayed by default in my app: the **HomePage**.

***Would you have an explanation?***

**Edit:**

Thanks to @Dmitriy Kirakosyan, I did some new tests: I've seen that in **Debug** mode too, **the HomePage display's event is no longer tracked.** In **AppCenter** I can see traces dating back for long weeks ago, but not for the latest weeks.

This could be related to the packages updates (Xamarin.Forms, AppCenter, ...) cause I didn't change the AppCenter initialization or the event tracking...

What is strange is that I can see in **Debug** mode that `AppCenter.Start()` is well called before the **HomePage** display tracking.

But when I check the values of `AppCenter.Configured` or `Analytics.IsEnabledAsync()` just before this tracking, there are both `False`:

```
var test1 = AppCenter.Configured;
var test2 = Analytics.IsEnabledAsync().Result;
_eventTracker.Display(EventPage.HomePage);
```

Comment: check [linker settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) for release mode

Comment: I'm using the "Link SDK Assemblies" option. But if it's related to this, I should neither have the tracking for the other pages, as it's related to the same assembly, isn't it? And as I explained, the tracking of the other pages is well managed in AppCenter: it's only for the HomePage that I don't get the information...

Comment: I've tried with "Don't link" option, but it's the same result. So I don't have any idea...

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code for AppCenterEventTracker.cs? I have a hunch that you're not calling `AppCenter.Start`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#423-xamarinforms

Comment: Hi @BrandonMinnick I've added some code and explanations. The call to `AppCenter.Start()` is well done as the other pages display are well visible in **AppCenter**: it's only the **HomePage** that I can't see....

Comment: Double check the unique ID that you're passing into AppCenter.Start for the Release configuration and ensure it matches the unique ID that App Center provides. This is the only thing I can think of that explains why your code is working in Debug and not in Release.

Comment: It's not possible: for the other pages than **HomePage**, I can see the display events in AppCenter for the Release.

Comment: Could you check if AppCenter is configured in the `HomeViewModel()` ctor? Eg. check if `AppCenter.Configured` and `Analytics.IsEnabledAsync()` return `true`.

Comment: Hi @DmitriyKirakosyan I've checked the values: both are `False` in `Debug` and `Release` mode. If I check the same values on another ViewModel there are `True`. However, the event is well managed by AppCenter in `Debug`mode...

Comment: @Gold.strike, I'll try to reproduce it. Meanwhile, if you have time to create a sample app demonstrating this issue, that would help a lot.

Comment: @Gold.strike For some reason your `HomeViewModel` is initializing faster than AppCenter, even though you call AppCenter in `OnStart`. Could you also check if/why the view model ctor is called before(or in parallel?) the AppCenter.Start. You can check that via debugging and inspecting the call stack.

Comment: @DmitriyKirakosyan I've did some news tests and I've edited the description of the issue. Finally I encounter the same issue in Debug/Release mode. It's strange as it seems that `OnStart` is well called before the `HomeViewModel` Ctor...

Comment: @Gold.strike, I confirm that the issue exists for appcenter dotnet sdk. It's because your first fragment is creating in App.xaml.cs constructor. So your main view model is creating earlier than OnStart is called in which AppCenter is starting.
So put the AppCenter.Start in the App's constructor instead right before your HomePage view creation. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @DmitriyKirakosyan in Debug mode it seems to be good. I will create new realease on AppCenter to check if it's good too.